# missing factors when `unlist()` or `flatten()` a list

Tags: r, list, factors

When unlisting `unlist()` or flattening `flatten()` a list with a factor variable, factors values are lost in the process. Additionally, when `unlist()` everything is converted into "character". Which is the correct way to proceed? Below is my desired output. Thanks.

```
L <- list(x = structure(1L, .Label = c("Jujutsu", "Kaisen"), class = "factor"), 
          y = 2020,
          z = "Shinjuku")
```

#### `unlist()`

```
unlist(L)
# x          y          z 
# "1"     "2020" "Shinjuku"
```

#### `flatten()`

```
flatten(L)
# $x
# [1] 1
# 
# $y
# [1] 2020
# 
# $z
# [1] "Shinjuku"
```

#### Desired output.

```
# $x
# [1] "Jujutsu" 
# 
# $y
# [1] 2020
# 
# $z
# [1] "Shinjuku"
```

Comment: Desired output is a list with characters? Better to keep the desired output reproducible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
map(.x = L, ~ if(is.factor(.x)) as.character(.x) else .x)

$x
[1] "Jujutsu"

$y
[1] 2020

$z
[1] "Shinjuku"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for `is.factor` and convert the subset.

```
f <- sapply(L, is.factor)
L[f] <- lapply(L[f], as.character)
L
# $x
# [1] "Jujutsu"
# 
# $y
# [1] 2020
# 
# $z
# [1] "Shinjuku"
```

This also gives you the vector.

```
unlist(L)
#         x          y          z 
# "Jujutsu"     "2020" "Shinjuku"
```

The "2020" will stay character though, because all elements of a vector have to be the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Try `type.convert` if you are with base R

```
> type.convert(L, as.is = TRUE)
$x
[1] "Jujutsu"

$y
[1] 2020

$z
[1] "Shinjuku"
```